# Why doesn't it show me the values in my DataGrid that I assign in the DataTable?

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid

I initially wrote the headers manually in my DataGrid and now I want to fill the DataGrid from a DataTable. I wanted to do it like this:

```
void fillingDataGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn id = new DataColumn("id", typeof(int));
        DataColumn name = new DataColumn("name", typeof(string));
        DataColumn ort = new DataColumn("ort", typeof(string));
        DataColumn alter = new DataColumn("alter", typeof(string));
        DataColumn land = new DataColumn("land", typeof(string));

        dt.Columns.Add(id);
        dt.Columns.Add(name);
        dt.Columns.Add(ort);
        dt.Columns.Add(alter);
        dt.Columns.Add(land);

        DataRow firstrow = dt.NewRow();
        firstrow[0] = 1;
        firstrow[1] = "Peter";
        firstrow[2] = "Berlin";
        firstrow[3] = "18";
        firstrow[4] = "Germany";

        DataRow secondrow = dt.NewRow();
        firstrow[0] = 2;
        firstrow[1] = "Karl";
        firstrow[2] = "Prag";
        firstrow[3] = "12";
        firstrow[4] = "Tschechien";

        dt.Rows.Add(firstrow);
        dt.Rows.Add(secondrow);

        gridd.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.fillingDataGrid();
    }
```

The problem, however, is that if I do it this way, it is not output correctly because it looks like this:

[image: Picture1]

Why doesn't it show me all the data, what do I have to change on my DataTable?

Comment: What is `gridd`? Is event handled being wired up correctly? Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: the name of my datagrid i give it the name gridd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

gridd.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

To :

gridd.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;

Comment: Then I don't get anything spent